# drop down menu that changes the name of a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an advanced search form and wish to set the name of a text input field via a drop down menu.

Here is a simple search form with three separate fields:

```
<form method="get" action="/search_results_advanced/" id="keyword">
    Search by name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    Search by address: <input type="text" name="address" value="">
    Search by phone number: <input type="text" name="phone" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" /> 
</form>
```

What I'd like to do is have a user select a single field from a drop down and then have a single text input box to enter a search term.

eg:

```
<form method="get" action="/search_results_advanced/" id="keyword">
    Search by:
    <select id="DropDownSelection">
        <option>Name</option>
        <option>Address</option>
        <option>Phone</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="?NAME_FROM_DROPDOWN_SELECTION?" value="" id="searchbar" size="25" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" /> 
</form>
```

How can I name the text field using the dropdown selection? I tried modifying some javascript I found via google but I'm afraid I just don't know javascript at all and didn't get anywhere.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you include the javascript that you tried? Stackoverflow is for helping you troubleshoot your problem, not doing it for you, so you might have more luck posting some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is one example I made using jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').on('change','#DropDownSelection',function(){
  var v = $('#DropDownSelection').val();
  $('.search-by').html('Search by '+v+': <input type="text" name="'+v+'" value="">');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action="/search_results_advanced/" id="keyword">
    Search by:
    <select id="DropDownSelection">
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
        <option value="Address">Address</option>
        <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
    </select>
    <div class="search-by">Search by Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value=""></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jquery, it's pretty simple:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#DropDownSelection').change(function() {
            $('#searchbar').attr('name', $('#DropDownSelection').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `value` for each `option`, and listen to `change` event on the dropdown:

```js
var dd = document.getElementById('DropDownSelection');
var input = document.getElementById('searchbar');
input.setAttribute('name', 'name'); // default value

dd.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  input.setAttribute('name', e.target.value); // set input.name equal to chosen select.value
  console.log(input.getAttribute('name'))
})
```

```html
<form method="get" action="/search_results_advanced/" id="keyword">
    Search by:
    <select id="DropDownSelection">
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        <option value="address">Address</option>
        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" id="searchbar" size="25" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" /> 
</form>
```